# Decryption negating special character like " !@#$%^&*()"

Tags: c#, encryption

I was wondering how am i able to negate away the special character.
For example when i key aaa for my decrypted text and move 3 space behind, it shows it ^^^ instead of www. Is there anything wrong with my coding?
This is all the code that i have inside my c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string UserInput = "";
    int shift;
    Shift OBSHIFT = new Shift();
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Ceasar Shift Program:");
    Console.WriteLine("********************************");
    Console.WriteLine("type a string to encrypt:");
    UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How many chars would you like to shift?: :");
    shift = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Your encrypted string is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(OBSHIFT.Decrypt(UserInput, -shift));
    Console.Read();
}
class Shift
{
    public string Decrypt(string cipherString, int shift)
    {
        string userOutput = "";
        char[] a = cipherString.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherString.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = a[i];
            int temp;
            if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))
            {
                temp = (int)(a[i] + shift);
                if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' && temp > 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' && temp > 'z'))
                    temp = temp + 26;
                else
                    temp = (int)(a[i] + (shift));
            }
            else
                temp = c;
            userOutput += (char)temp;
        }
        return userOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a *complete* example. You've *nearly* got it already, but adding enough so that we could just copy/paste/compile/run would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code which does the actual shifting:

```
if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))
{
    temp = (int)(a[i] + shift);
    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' && temp > 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' && temp > 'z'))
        temp = temp + 26;
    else
        temp = (int)(a[i] + (shift));
}
```

I would suggest restructuring in a few ways:

- Make sure your shift is always positive to start with, so you only need to worry about going "past" the end of a particular set of characters
- Use two separate branches, one for a-z and one for A-Z
- Use a `StringBuilder` to build your string instead of repeated string concatenation

So for example:

```
public string ShiftText(string input, int shift)
{
    // This makes sure the shift is *always* in the range 0-25.
    shift = ((shift % 26) + 26) % 26;

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        {
            // We'll sort this later
        }
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            // We'll sort this later
        }
        else
        {
            output.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Now the bits inside the "sort this later" are simpler to work with. For the a-z part, for example:

```
int shifted = c + shift;
if (shifted > 'z')
{
    shifted -= 26;
}
output.Append((char) shifted);
```

... and then the same for A-Z, but testing against 'Z' instead of 'z'. Yes, this is effectively duplicate code - but it's only there twice, and I think it's simpler to have that duplication than extract it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with this type of code instead:

```
public class Shift
{
    public string Decrypt(string cipherString, int shift)
    {
        var alphabet =
            Enumerable
            .Concat(
                Enumerable.Range((int)'a', 26),
                Enumerable.Range((int)'A', 26))
            .Select(i => (char)i)
            .ToArray();

        var map =
            alphabet
                .Zip(
                    alphabet.Concat(alphabet).Concat(alphabet).Skip(alphabet.Length + shift),
                    (c0, c1) => new { c0, c1 })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.c0, x => x.c1);

        return String.Join("", cipherString.Select(x => map.ContainsKey(x) ? map[x] : x));
    }
}
```

The three parts are nicely distinct. (1) the `alphabet` is built. It can contain any number of characters, so long as there are no repeats. (1) the `map` is simply a dictionary built by mapping the alphabet to the alphabet shifted by `shift` characters. (3) returns the input `cypherString` mapped by the `map` where the key exists.